# kernel_gem.rb:67:in `synchronize': deadlock; recursive locking (ThreadError)

Tags: ruby

when I run this command on macOS Big Sur 11.2.3:

```
pod setup
```

shows this error:

```
$ pod setup                                                                                                                                                           ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Traceback (most recent call last):
    12: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
    11: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    10: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
     9: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `activate_bin_path'
     8: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `synchronize'
     7: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:306:in `block in activate_bin_path'
     6: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:243:in `finish_resolve'
     5: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:435:in `resolve_current'
     4: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:435:in `new'
     3: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/resolver/set.rb:24:in `initialize'
     2: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:42:in `require'
     1: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `gem'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `synchronize': deadlock; recursive locking (ThreadError)
(base)
```

I am searching from internet but did not found some useful imformation about this problem. I have tried to reinstall `cocoapods` still not fix this. what should I do to fix this problem? this is my ruby env:

```
~/source/cruise-open on  main ⌚ 13:37:15
$ rvm list                                                                                                                                                            ‹ruby-2.7.2›
=* ruby-2.7.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-3.0.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

(base)
```

right now I found run `pod install` command still show this error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Updating RubyGems did the trick for me.

https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-update

`gem update --system`

Answer (score 0):

This error must be for any rails application. Check the ruby and rails version from the Gemfile. In my case, it's ruby 3.1.2 and rails 7.0.4.

Reinstall or Install the dependencies again. Ruby 3.1.2 is already there in my system but I reinstalled in order to fix this issue.

Remove the bundler from /.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/cache
rm -rf bundler-2.3.25.gem
My Gemfile.lock was bundled with 2.3.25
And remove ruby from /.rvm/gems
rm -rf ruby-3.1.2

Now the error will be changed when you install rails or bundle to something
invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError) in /Users/anjanasingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/cache/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10.gem

Now, uninstall ruby using rvm(Yes, rvm works in my case though I used rbenv for setting the ruby versions)

- rvm uninstall "ruby-3.1.2

Install ruby

- rvm install "ruby-3.1.2"

bundle your application

- bundle install

Rails is still not there. So, install rails

- gem install rails -v 7.0.4

I have tried with 'rbenv install 3.1.2' and reinstall, install[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT6uT.png) multiple times but it was not working with rbenv. Finally rvm worked.